# Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu 13.10 built-in display not working

Tags: 13.10, dell, display, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 which came pre-installed with Windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and upgraded to 13.10 recently. After the upgrade, the built-in display is always a blank screen, while when connected to the external monitor, everything displays properly there. I am new to Ubuntu and would like any solutions to resolve this problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Though this might be separate from [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) since here one monitor works and another does not, it would be helpful to include information about whether or not any answers there helped (with details about what happened even for possible solutions that did not). This might still be closed as a duplicate--or as unclear--without that information, but if you edit your question, it will be automatically considered for reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have a "*Function* + ? (*key with small picture of a monitor or screen*)?
 Normally they are included and used for toggling between displays. on some models they are tied into the BIOS and their functionis independant of the OS.Take alook and let us know.